# what is limit of a repeater in asp.net or how many records I can fetch in asp:repeater at a time

Tags: asp.net

I am getting an error when running a webpage (aspx) i.e.
**Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.**

I am trying to show data from database in a repeater and number of records are  **"1180805"**.

Can anyone tell me what is limit of a repeater means how many rows I can fetch.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to display a million records at once? But I think the error is because of some calculation you are doing, not only "number of records"

Comment: nope actually I don't. I need to show only few record there. In short I was just doing R&D there :) and suddenly i got this error.
I thought everybody should be aware of this.

And if there was an error because of some calculation than it should also now show records when i put ** Where rownum < 10 **

Answer (score 0):

yes this error was coming because of number of record i reduced number or records by using `where rownum < 10` by this it fetched only 9 records and displayed in repeater. now I have to do paging for repeater and at each page i have to fetch further records...

Comment: but still I don't know what is limit of a asp: repeater.